# Running java dataflow pipeline locally with PubSub

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run locally (with local runner), in Eclipse, a Java dataflow which use Apache Beam.

The problem occurs when I added pubsub as the data source.
 (If I delete that line and try with a simple pipeline, I can execute it without problem)

**The pipeline code:**

```
public class StarterPipeline {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
    run(options);
  }

public static PipelineResult run(Options options) {

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    /*
     * Step 1: Read from PubSub
     */
    PCollection<PubsubMessage> messages = null;
    if (options.getUseSubscription()) {
        messages = pipeline.apply("ReadPubSubSubscription", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
                .fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()).withIdAttribute("messageId"));
    } else {
        messages = pipeline.apply("ReadPubSubTopic", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
                .fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()).withIdAttribute("messageId"));
    }

     <...>
    return pipeline.run();
}
```

**And the error message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/util/DoFnAndMainOutput
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:462)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$1.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:160)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.payloadForParDoLike(ParDoTranslation.java:695)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateParDo(ParDoTranslation.java:156)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$ParDoPayloadTranslator.translate(ParDoTranslation.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.toProto(PTransformTranslation.java:206)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.getParDoPayload(ParDoTranslation.java:547)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.isSplittable(ParDoTranslation.java:557)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformMatchers$4.matches(PTransformMatchers.java:194)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$2.visitPrimitiveTransform(Pipeline.java:282)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:665)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:251)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:460)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replace(Pipeline.java:260)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replaceAll(Pipeline.java:210)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:170)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:315)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:301)
    at com.accenture.pipeline.StarterPipeline.run(StarterPipeline.java:128)
    at com.accenture.pipeline.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.DoFnAndMainOutput
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 26 more
```

To execute the pipeline locally I have tried to run with:

- Maven
- Dataflow SDK

With the following options:

**DATAFLOW**
[image: maven]

**MAVEN**
[image: dataflow]

Should I add any dependency?

---

If you need any further details, let me know.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, seems like you are using DirectRunnner not DataflowRunner. Can you refer to following to properly setup your Dataflow pipeline ? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven Unfortunately seems like provided eclipse plugin does not work for latest versions of Beam if you were trying to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve that, I added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Run pipeline in locally(not on dataflow) use following commands in terminal**

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/GCP CREDENTIAL FULL 
PATH/credential.json
```

then Run this command to Run pipeline in local

```
   mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=PACKAGENAME.CLASS_NAME "-Dexec.args=--project=PROJECT_NAME --numWorkers=2 --autoscalingAlgorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED --workerMachineType=n1-standard-8 --jobName=PIPELINE_NAME"
```

**To Run Pipeline in IntelliJ for Debug or LOCAL**

```
Go to Run Debug Configuration -> Click on Plus -> Select maven -> working directory (select directory of pipeline ) -> command line (add above command) . Then go to Runner -> Uncheck Project Setting -> Select JRE -> add credential path with above export command
```